# Storing short strings and numeric values in resources in Android

Tags: android, java.util.scanner

I want to have some static numeric and text values as an application resource. For example my data is like this:

```
Levels 5 First_Level 500 60 1 Second_Level 500 80 1 Third_Level 200 60 1 Fourth_Level 130 30 2 Final_Level 100 30 3
... and another 300 lines...
```

The format and order of the data is predefined and guaranteed to be valid.

I could read it with `java.util.Scanner`, but it's extremely slow in Android, reading a 10 KB file takes minutes. It's slow because of the regular-expression-based pattern matching inside (when I traceview'ed it).

What way would you suggest to store them?

Answer (score 1):

You can store it in a object arraylist, that object just implements Serializable.

Then just ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(list), and later use readObject.

Comment: just that object serialization is probably the slowest possible approach :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can store it as raw data in `resources/raw` (e.g. as CSV or TSV) and use [Resources.openRawResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource(int)) to read from it using an InputStream. That should be reasonably fast.

Comment: Forgot to mention, this is what I did. The problem is that parsing the numbers are very slow.

Comment: you're saying a 10KB file takes *minutes*? I don't know that Scanner class, but have you tried using a simple BufferedReader and a simple tokenizer or split expression? I can't believe this would take longer than a couple seconds.

Answer (score 1):

After more than a year of Android development, I now know several options:

1. Store strings, integers, etc as string/integer resources. Put `<string name="mystring">My String</string>` or `<integer name="myint">123</integer>` and reference them using `R.string.mystring` or `R.integer.myint`. The drawback is there can be no nesting, so we will have difficulties storing structured data.
2. Use xml files under `res/xml`. Surprisingly, they are compiled to binary-xml which parses the integers, booleans, floats, etc to machine format and can be read very quickly. Use `Resources#getXml` to get the parser, and then use methods such as `getAttributeIntValue("attribute_name")` to get the value as int directly.
3. Use `Parcel`-ed binary file. The [android.os.Parcel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html) is a very fast way to store values of various types. You can implement `Parcelable` to your own data structure to support that.